# ant debug not working

Tags: android, ant

I am trying to compile simple Hello World program mentioned in the
website.My Ant is not able to compile the code , it wants version
1.8.0 or higher version. I have downloaded almost all tye of ants from
Apache website

1. all the binaries are 1.7 version
2. source code I am not able to compile getting following error

   ... Bootstrapping Ant Distribution
   ... Compiling Ant Classes
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/
   tools/javac/Main
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.Main
          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
          at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
          at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
          at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.jav
   Could not find the main class: com.sun.tools.javac.Main. Program will
   exit.
   ... Failed compiling Ant classes !
   Bootstrap FAILED

for these errors , i have tried defining class path.

Regards
Sidharth Rai

Answer (score 0):

> all the binaries are 1.7 version

No, they are not. If you visit the [Apache Ant Web site's download page](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi), you can download Ant 1.8.2 from any of the mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have not set the **JAVA_HOME** variable to point at a Java JDK. See the ANT installation instructions:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#advanced

Rather confusingly Java comes in two flavours, JRE and the JDK. It's the latter that contains tools like *javac* for compiling java code.